# What do i need for SSL besides a certificate?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ssl, chargify

We're looking to use [Chargify](http://www.chargify.com), a payment API and to do so you need to make card-related requests over SSL.

Our hosting provider ([Memset](http://www.memset.com)) offer SSL certificated for an annual fee.

> Once I have the certificate, what do I
>   need to do to use it?
>
> What security issues are there that I
>   need to look into?

Answer (score 0):

SSL can use only server's certificate OR it can also require use of certificate for client-side authentication as well.

IF you need a client-side certificate to authenticate your software on the server, you first of all need to ensure that the certificate you buy from your hosting provider will be accepted by the server. It can happen that the server owners issue their own certificates or that they accept only some particular certificates.

But from [description on Chargify site](http://docs.chargify.com/api-authentication) I don't see that you need to authenticate with a client-side certificate. It's regular SSL where you connect, validate server's certificate and if it's ok, continue communication by authenticating yourself using custom generated key (see the description for details).

So for me it seems that you need to contact Chargify with your question (if it needs further clarifiction), not StackOverflow.

Comment: my question is intended to be more general. I'm completely new to SSL and was looking for some explanations of how it should be used as a piece of technology

Comment: @Haroldo we have description of SSL basics here (http://www.eldos.com/security/articles/1948.php) and here (http://www.eldos.com/security/articles/1951.php) and I also recommend everyone reading the book "Rsa Security's Official Guide to Cryptography".

Comment: @Haroldo: The first 2 paragraphs of Eugene's answer are more general.